# Timer Multithreading array sharing one function problems

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an multithreading timer array, each one calling the same function. to do the same task but passing different value to the function. But the price calculate is not accurate due to other threads pass in the value same time. How to efficiency way to solve this, i have an idea is pass in the an int ID to identify is different calculation.

```
   ListOfValue ListOfValue[ListOfValue.ID] = ListOfValue;
   double totalPriceSolve[ListOfValue.ID] = 
          ListOfValue[ListOfValue.ID].priceA + ListOfValue[ListOfValue.ID].PriceB;
```

But above solution i think look not efficiency turn all data into array and i not sure is thread-safe or not.

Simplify Demo example as below calculation is too short may can't see the problems.

```
System.Threading.Timer[] timerThread = new System.Threading.Timer[10]; 

for(int i=0; i< 10; i++){
    timerThread[i] = new System.Threading.Timer(
                     new TimerCallback(MultiTimerTick2), ListOfValue ,2000, 2000);
}

private void MultiTimerTick2(object obj){
    ListOfValue ListOfValue = (ListOfValue)obj;
    //Perform job like read data from database, after calculation insert into database
    double totalPrice = ListOfValue.priceA + ListOfValue.PriceB;
}
```

Comment: Your code as is written now should not have any problems as there is no visible modification of "ListOfValue" collections. Since code does not look like it will compile (type of magical `ListOfType` used as type, collection and value at the same type is unclear) not much more info can be provided. Side note: please *do not* use `double` for financial computations - use `decimal`.

Comment: .net 4 has thread safe collections. Otherwise, look up lock().

Answer (score 0):

Your code variables seem to be thread safe, your working with an array and you don't modify it. I can see two problems:

1) Using double for calculation. Usually double is not precise for financial compurations (as Alexei mentioned).

2) You'r reading and writting data from database, so actually it's not safe because you don't use lock, so there could be a situation like this:

```
Thread1 read A from DB
Thread2 read A from DB
Thread1 modify A based on read value
Thread1 write A to DB
Thread2 modify A based on read (old) value
Thread2 write A to DB
```